# What does it mean to say $d$ is a real differential operator?

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, differential-forms, kahler-manifolds

I'm reading about Hodge Theory from Griffiths and Harris. The setup is as follows.

$M$ is a compact Kahler manifold with Kahler form $w$. We have the well known operators $d , \partial , \bar{\partial}$. We define another set of operators $L$ and $\Lambda$. $L(\theta) = \theta \wedge w$. And $\Lambda$ is the adjoint of $L$.

Then they go on to write that :

"$d , d^c = i.(\bar{\partial} - \partial), \Lambda$ are real differential operators."

> In what sense are these **real**?

Comment: I think this means they commute with the conjugation operator acting on complex-valued differential forms.

Comment: It's understandable for $d$. How would one show it for the other two? Can you please explain

Comment: For the $\Lambda$ one, I'd suggest taking a look at Huybrechts *Complex Geometry*, Section 1.2, and understanding why the Kähler form itself is real, in a very precise sense. For the $i(\partial - \bar{\partial})$ you can use $\partial f = \bar{\partial}\bar{f}$ and $\partial \bar{f} = \bar{\partial}f$ for a complex valued function $f$ (and for thus for complex valued differential forms).

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment, but not an answer.

As a brief explanation on why $\Lambda$ is real: the fundamental Kähler form can be defined as a real 2-form, i.e. as a smooth section of $\Lambda^2 T^*\underline{M}$, where $\underline{M}$ is the real manifold underlying $M$. Then you can embed these real 2-forms into the complex-valued 2-forms via the complexification map. The image under this map of the real $\omega$ happens to land on the $(1,1)$ term of the decomposition
$$
\Lambda^2 T^*_\mathbb{C}M = \Lambda^{2,0} T^*M \oplus \Lambda^{1,1} T^*M \oplus \Lambda^{0,2} T^*M
$$
and thus the Lefschetz operators $\Lambda,L$ are the complexification of the same *real* operators.

This is very thoroughly explained, as I said, in Huybrechts Section 1.2.

Comment: At this point I'd like to ask a question : by a Kahler manifold I understand a symplectic manifold with a complex structure and some compatibility conditions. The Kahler form (which is actually the symplectic form) is supposed to be **real valued** or real in the sense that $w = \bar{w}$?

Comment: If you see it as the usual symplectic form, a section of $\Lambda^2 T^*\underline{M}$ it is of course real valued, and there is not even a conjugation defined.

When you see it as a section of $\Lambda^{1,1} T^*M$ (the (1,1)-component of the complexification of the above bundle $\Lambda^2 T^*\underline{M}$) it satisfies $\bar{\omega} = \omega$, which in turn, implies that it is **real valued over real vectors** (those in the image of the embedding $T^*\underline{M} \hookrightarrow T^*\underline{M}\otimes \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Let us take your typical Kähler form over $\mathbb{C}$ ($\mathbb{R}^2$ as a real manifold), given by $\omega = dx\wedge dy$ in real coordinates. You can see that it image in the complexified world is given by
$\omega = \frac{i}{2} dz \wedge d \bar{z}$, where $dz = dx\otimes 1 + dy \otimes i, d\bar{z} = dx \otimes 1 - dy\otimes i$.

Then, expanding it will yield $\omega' = (dx \wedge dy)\otimes 1$, which is very natural. You can check that over evaluated over **real vectors**, namely those of the form $v\otimes 1$, $\omega'$ is real valued.

Comment: Now, usually one abuses of notation and uses $\omega$ to designate the original Kähler form and its image in the complexification.

Comment: Thank you very much for a detailed answer. It always bugged me what **real** form actually meant.

Answer (score 0):

It just means that they are differential operators if you consider them as acting on real-valued functions. Here this just means they satisfy the product rule if you apply them to a product of two functions.

This is in contrast to the concept of [complex differentiable](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexDifferentiable.html) which relates to functions that are holomorphic.